# Counting the running app from start and finish datetime column in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'app': [1,2,3,4,5],
'start_time': ['2022-03-11 22:26:00', '2022-03-11 22:26:30', '2022-03-11 22:27:00', '2022-03-11 22:27:30', '2022-03-11 22:28:00'],
'finish_time': ['2022-03-11 22:26:40', '2022-03-11 22:27:00', '2022-03-11 22:28:00', '2022-03-11 22:27:40', '2022-03-11 22:29:00']
})

df['start_time']=pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'])
df['finish_time']=pd.to_datetime(df['finish_time'])
```

My main purpose is to create a plot x-axis is time, y-axis is the count of running app

By that way, my idea is to create new column which is equal the running app when the app is started. For example in this case when the app 2 start actually app 1 is still running (it is fine if app 2 is included in the counting process), but I am stuck here (this is the example of the dataframe that I intended to make)

```
    app start_time  finish_time  running_apps(if current app included)
0   1   2022-03-11 22:26:00 2022-03-11 22:26:40 1
1   2   2022-03-11 22:26:30 2022-03-11 22:27:00 2
2   3   2022-03-11 22:27:00 2022-03-11 22:28:00 2
3   4   2022-03-11 22:27:30 2022-03-11 22:27:40 2
4   5   2022-03-11 22:28:00 2022-03-11 22:29:00 2
```

if someone else has another idea, it would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use numpy broadcasting with `np.tril` for lower triangle for test next datetimes, chain bot hmask and count `True`s by `sum`:

```
df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'])
df['finish_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['finish_time'])

a = np.tril(df['finish_time'].to_numpy() > df['start_time'].to_numpy()[:,None])
b = np.tril(df['start_time'].to_numpy() < df['finish_time'].to_numpy()[:,None])

df['count'] = (a & b).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   app          start_time         finish_time  count
0    1 2022-03-11 22:26:00 2022-03-11 22:26:40      1
1    2 2022-03-11 22:26:30 2022-03-11 22:27:00      2
2    3 2022-03-11 22:27:00 2022-03-11 22:28:00      1
3    4 2022-03-11 22:27:30 2022-03-11 22:27:40      2
4    5 2022-03-11 22:28:00 2022-03-11 22:29:00      1
```

Or if need compare between all values:

```
df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'])
df['finish_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['finish_time'])

a = (df['finish_time'].to_numpy() > df['start_time'].to_numpy()[:,None])
b = (df['start_time'].to_numpy() < df['finish_time'].to_numpy()[:,None])

df['count'] = (a & b).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   app          start_time         finish_time  count
0    1 2022-03-11 22:26:00 2022-03-11 22:26:40      2
1    2 2022-03-11 22:26:30 2022-03-11 22:27:00      2
2    3 2022-03-11 22:27:00 2022-03-11 22:28:00      2
3    4 2022-03-11 22:27:30 2022-03-11 22:27:40      2
4    5 2022-03-11 22:28:00 2022-03-11 22:29:00      1
```

Comment: thank you, I think I understand how it works by reading np.tril documentation and printing a, b